# mongodb aggregate: how to get count with 2 parameters

Tags: mongodb

I have a data set with this structure:

```
{
"price" : 48.00"
"year" : "2008",
"model" : "something",
"manufacturer" : "ACME",
"productgroup" : "3629",
}
```

I want to count how many `items` a manufacturer has per `product group`, so the output for the above sample data, would be:

```
{productgroup:"3629", manufacturer: "ACME", count: 34 }
```

I do everything in `mongo shell/robomongo` and i am glad for every hint how to tackle this.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below query.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
{$group: 
    {
     "_id": {"pr": "$productgroup", "mn": "$manufacturer"}, 
     "count": {$sum:1}
    }
})
```

The idea is to have both the fields specified in the _id field of group.

Comment: thanks lalit, and thanks for the link 
"Mongodb Aggregation Framework | Group over multiple values?", but the link really doesnt help me as i don't see how to solve my problem with the information given.